# How to select button after clicking on image view in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

**strong text**hi guys i am trying to figure out something i am using android studio and in the i add an image to and then a button . After that i select image by clicking on it and now i try to click on button but i cannot click on button any more how can i fix it please any idea . I select image view and now i cannot select the button i keep trying to click on button to see change id or anything but i cannot even click on it any solution remember is a very little problem but i am a beginner thanks.

Update: -

hi the solution is very simple in the android studio suppose i add an image view then i add a button in the right bottom . Then i click on button and set id and other stuff but after that as i clicked to image view i was able to click to image view but after clicking on image view i was not able to click on the button any more i keep trying the problem was very simple . The only thing i need to do is to do a click out side of design area and then click to any button or image view i want that was the trick .

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. When posting a question please also post your code so that we can better help with your issue. Remember to only post the relevant  (yet sufficient) code.

Comment: ok but this quesiton is not about the code is about the layout

Comment: Your question is unclearly formulated. It appears to be about the click function. Nowhere in the question do you talk about "Layout". Regardless, if it is about the layout you will most probably have a xml layout file. That is also "code"--so post it.

Comment: ok i am new is so complicated for me

Comment: No, problem! But, you will often find that questions without code will be ignored. Most SO users need to see the code to really provide a workable solution.

Comment: As there is no layout.xml, So i think you should try changing the height and width of imageView from wrap_content to specific size say 100dp and 100dp. I think this will possibly solve your problem as selected image is taking its size own screen and it hides the button (but you can see the button as the image can be transparent but you cannot click  the button.

Comment: hi the solution is very simple in the android studio suppose i add an image view then i add a button in the right bottom . Then i click on button and set id and other stuff but after that as i clicked to image view i was able to click to image view but after clicking on image view i was not able to click on the button any more i keep trying the problem was very simple . The only thing i need to do is to do a click out side of design area and then click to any button or image view i want that was the trick .